# KLEIN Paradox phenomena

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, dirac-equation

We considered the case of a relativistic fermionic particle in a potential well. We divided the region in two zones, the one where the potential is zero and the one where it has a values $V_0$.

The solutions were given to us (without derivation):
Region I:

$\Psi_I^{inc}=Ae^{ik_1z}(1,0,\frac{k_1}{E+m},0)$

$\Psi_I^{ref}=Be^{-ik_1z}(1,0,\frac{-k_1}{E+m},0)+B'e^{-ik_1z}(0,1,0,\frac{k_1}{E+m})$

For Region 2:

$\Psi_{II}^{trans}=De^{ik_2z}(1,0,\frac{k_2}{E-V_0+m},0)+D'e^{ik_2z}(0,1,0,\frac{-k_2}{E-V_0+m})$

Note:$k_2^2=(E-m-v_0)(E+m-v_0)$

By considering the continuity, in the region where the potential changes we end up with some conclusions:

1. If $|E-v_0|<m$ then $k_2$ is imaginary, which means there is an exponential damping in the 2nd region where the potential is present.
2. If $v_0>E+m$ then k_2 is real and we have oscillations in the 2nd region.

I have the following 3 questions:

1. How do we come up with these solutions (given above).
2. The fermions have, initially, energy: $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$. Now does this energy expression includes the potential energy, or is this always, an expression for the kinetic and the rest mass energy of a particle?
3. What exactly does it mean $E+m$ ?

Comment: Sometimes you have $E$ and $m$ in different unites: $E = mc^2$. But sometimes you use units like seconds and light-seconds, where $c=1$. In that case $E = m$. Did the units get mixed?

Comment: But, the energy of the incident particles  must be the relativistic dispersion relation, in this case right?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to imply that $E = m$ in your problem. Just using $E = mc^2$ to illustrate units.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of these conventions, but I don't understand what it means when we say E+m? because E itself contain m and p, right?

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_paradox